# Delete old job builds that were built by a SPECIFIC user

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jobs

I was wondering if its possible to delete old builds that were built by a specific user?
I know i can use a script in the jenkins script console and delete old builds by their numbers, but is there a way to filter them by who ran them?
thnx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Groovy script to do this. I have commented out the actual delete line and added a println for safety. Please adjust the script as required.

```
def userNameToCheck="admin"
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { jobitem ->
          def jobName = jobitem.name
          def jobInfo = Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName)
         
         if(jobInfo.getLastBuild()){
           
            def lastBuildNum=jobInfo.getLastBuild().getNumber()
            def deletedNumRange = Fingerprint.RangeSet.fromString("0-${lastBuildNum}",false);
            def buildCount=jobInfo.getBuilds(deletedNumRange).size()
               
             if(buildCount==0){
                 println("No build logs found in  ${jobName} and build history count is : ${buildCount}")
             }
             else{
                 jobInfo.getBuilds(deletedNumRange).each { item ->     
                 // Check if the build was executed by the specified user                      
                   if(item.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause).getUserId().equals(userNameToCheck)) {
                     //item.delete()
                    println("Deleting a Build. For JOB : " + jobName + " for user "   + item.getCause(Cause.UserIdCause).getUserId())
                   }                            
                 }
             }
           } else {
                  println("No builds found in ${jobName}")
           }
   }
```